# Kafka connect avro consumer in scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a producer using kafka connect which uses Confluent Kafka Connect API and it publish the messages in a "SourceRecord" format, which contains "schema" and "struct" as below.

I am looking for a sample code to build out a kafka consumer in scala, which consumes the message and deserialize it into an object

```
import org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceTask;

//publish kafka message in avro format 

    protected SourceRecord makeSourceRecord(AvroDataEvent avroDataEvent) {
        return new SourceRecord(
                partitionKey(config.sourceJdbcUrl),
                config.topicName,
                avroDataEvent.schema(),
                avroDataEvent.struct());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consume directly from the `config.topicName` topic using the Confluent KafkaAvroDeserializer class along with the schema registry that Connector is configured with

Just because data came from Connect doesn't require using the Connect API to read it.

Regarding sample code, try this as a starting point (it's in Kotlin) http://aseigneurin.github.io/2018/08/03/kafka-tutorial-5-consuming-avro.html